# Jtable tablecellrenderer?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer

I have a java gui using dtable and I'm trying to highlight the last row added. In my GUI.java file, I have the dtable created using:

```
public JTable display = new JTable(model){
public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column)
{
    Component c = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);

    c.setBackground(Color.GREEN);

    return c;
}
```

};

In my main.java file, I create the gui class instance 'gu' with dtable instance 'display' and add rows using:

```
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) gu.display.getModel();
model.addRow(new Object[] {"col1","col2"});
```

All I want to do is highlight the last added row using the renderer. What would be the code to invoke it?

Comment: What is the problem? Doesn't it work? is your whole table green?

Comment: I'm just not sure how to call prepareRenderer on the last dtable row? Would you be able to provide the statement?

Comment: I think you have to wrap the line
    c.setBackground(Color.GREEN); in something like if(row == this.getRowCount()-1)

Comment: Sorry I don't really understand... I just want something like display.getLastRow().setBackground(Color.GREEN)

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
public JTable display = new JTable(model) {
@Override
public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row,
            int column) {
        Component c = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);
        if (row == getColumnCount()) {
            c.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        } else {
            if (row % 2 == 0) {
                c.setBackground(UIManager.getColor("Table.background"));
            } else {
                c.setBackground(UIManager
                        .getColor("Table.alternateRowColor"));
            }
        }
        return c;
    }

};
```